# How to link to HTML page with a table with a button and have it input data from Firebase using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app I am creating. On the main page is a table with each row containing information. In each row there is a button "View More" that links to a new page with a standard table. Is there a way to make each View More button link to that view but fill in the table with different data related to each row from the main page.

Comment: You could have a GET parameter on that page, and fill the table accordingly. For example, redirect to `http://[yourURL]/[viewMoreID]`

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on that please?

Comment: If I understood right, when you click "View More", you redirect to a page with a default table, right? Let's say you're redirecting to `http://abcdef.com`. 
You could, on each row, have an id, and when you click on "View More", you redirect to a page with that id on the url, let's say `http://abcdef/[id-here]`. With `ui-router`, you can easily acess that id from `$stateParams`, and fill the table according to this id.

Comment: @user251663 Please, let me know if that made sense to you :)

Comment: Let's say on the main page I have 4 different rows that need to all go to the viewmore page and fill the table with their own information. So on the viewmore.html page, I'd have my table with let's say 3 rows. I'd create 1 id? or 4 ids?

Comment: Check if my answer helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

So, let's say you have 4 rows in the main page. You can assign each row an `id`.

```
Row 1 -> Redirects to "viewmore/1" 
Row 2 -> Redirects to "viewmore/2" 
Row 3 -> Redirects to "viewmore/3" 
Row 4 -> Redirects to "viewmore/4"
```

Since you're using `AngularJS`, you can use 
[ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). Here, you could define your `viewmore` state. Something like this:

```
.state('state1', {
    url: "/viewmore/:id",
    templateUrl: "partials/viewmore.html",
    controller: "ViewmoreCtrl"
})
```

On the controller, you can know what `id` is being used in the URL, using `$stateParams.id`. So, if you redirect to `viewmore/4`, you know that you want to display that from id 4.

```
module.controller('ViewmoreCtrl', function($stateParams, $state) {
    //fill table with data of id = $stateParams.id     
}
```

Comment: Okay it is starting to make more sense. However, so on the main page with the tables, I will never know how many rows I will have because they will change over time. How can I account for this? Rows can be deleted or added at any time.

Comment: Where those rows come from? A database? Are they just random? If they're random, how do you know what to show in the "viewmore" page? You should an unique `id` for each row, so you know what you should display in the "viewmore" page.

Comment: They come from a database(using Firebase). Each of them should have a unique id, so will I use that somehow? Also where would I define the viewmore state? In the viewmore.js file or in my main app.js ?

Comment: Yes, you should use their id on the redirect url - `viewmore/[id]`. That's how we defined the state. About the structure of the files, take a look here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure. The first structure is pretty common. The states (routing) are usually defined in the app.js file.